# How to say Welcome in Korean?

Tags: word-usage

The context is to welcome new members at an institution.

Found many ways of saying "welcome": 천만에요, 어서 오세요, 환영합니다, 환영하다.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

천만에요: replies to gratitude 
어서 오세요: shows hospitality to the guest (welcomes to an arrival or an entering a place.) 
환영합니다: also shows hospitality, and is also used to welcome new members to a group.

어서오세요 is mostly used in commercial places like tourist attractions, stores and restaurants, etc. 
환영합니다 is more general term for 'welcome'.

Welcome to a new member could be like: 
안녕하세요 (greeting), XX와 함께하게 된 것을 환영합니다 (welcomes to be one of XX).

Comment: Small correction: native Koreans don't reply 천만에요 to "thank you." There is no phrase that directly corresponds to "You're welcome" in Korean, and for some inexplicable reason, English textbooks in Korea mistranslated it into 천만에요, which really doesn't make much sense IMHO.  (But I did see some Korean Americans use the phrase, probably due to these textbooks.)

Comment: @jick It is true that the term "천만에요" is not used in verbal sense, but it can be often found in texts (well, they are mostly from 90s or older.) But yes, this term could be considered obsolete to actually use in real conversations.